# keypress using in SDL2 correctly?

Tags: c, keypress, rectangles, sdl-2

I tried to move a rectangle in a window by using keys from keyboard, but I get a Failreport with after start/compile my program.

```
  keystate=NULL;
if (keystate[SDLK_LEFT] ) 
{
  rect2.x -= 2;
}
if (keystate[SDLK_RIGHT] ) 
{
  rect2.x += 2;
}
if (keystate[SDLK_DOWN] ) 
{
  rect2.y += 2;
}
if (keystate[SDLK_UP] ) 
{
  rect2.y -= 2;
}
```

This is the code that not works. At the beginning of main() I put this line:

Uint8 *keystate;
I use the lib SDL.h in C to do this.

The failmessage contains:

> Program Received signal SIGSEGV
>   Stack trace is available in the 'Call Stack' tab
>   PS: After I think it is better to post the whole code . It is slightly modified :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>


int main()
{
  //Request successful execute
  if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)!=0)
  {
    printf("fehler");
    return 1;
  }

  //create window 800x600
  SDL_Window *win;
  win = SDL_CreateWindow("test",100,100,800,600,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

  //create renderwindow with vysnc enabled
  SDL_Renderer *ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

  if(ren==NULL)
  {
    printf("Fehler");
    SDL_Quit();
    return 1;
  }

  Uint8 *keystate=SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
  //boolean data type not supported
  int gameRunning = 1;

 SDL_Event event;

//create rectangle which is the whole window
 SDL_Rect rect={
    0,0,800,600
  };
  //smaller rectangle 
  SDL_Rect rect2={
    0,0,50,50
  };

//while loop to hold the window opened
  while (gameRunning)
  {
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))//close the window 
    {
      if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
      {
          gameRunning = 0;
      }
    }
    //color of the first rectangle(red)
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 255,0,0,255);
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
    SDL_RenderFillRect( ren, &rect );

    //second rectangle (blue)
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 0,0,255,255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect( ren, &rect2 );
    //change/update the render
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);

    //rect2.x+=5.f;

   if (keystate[SDLK_LEFT] ) 
    {
      rect2.x -= 2;
    }
    if (keystate[SDLK_RIGHT] ) 
    {
      rect2.x += 2;
    }
    if (keystate[SDLK_DOWN] ) 
    {
      rect2.y += 2;
    }
    if (keystate[SDLK_UP] ) 
    {
      rect2.y -= 2;
    }

  }
  //give heap free
  SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
  SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I get a Failreport with after start/compile my program" - It was at compile time or it compiled and crashed after running/starting the program?

Comment: I thing it compiled, started and then crashed.

Comment: Use a debugger and see where is crashing after you run it.That would be really helpful.

Comment: @student96 `keystate = NULL` and then reading `keystate[anything]` will segfault, since you are trying to dereference an invalid pointer. Maybe you meant `keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);`

Comment: when I do that I get the fail:"initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type"

Comment: @student96 then declare `const Uint8 *keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);` or const_cast it

Comment: but I noticed that I get this fail when i put it to another position too.

Comment: @PeterT this helped but now there is the messagebox again with the old problem.

Comment: @student96 which instruction causes the segfault now?

Comment: the if(keystate....) let the program crash. But there are no errors and no warnings.

Comment: @student96 you need to use the `SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT` and similar constants, `SDLK_LEFT` is wrong

Comment: @PeterT THATS IT! now it run correctly . But why do i use sdl_scancode and not sdlk?

Comment: @student96 because the documentation says so `Indexes into this array are obtained by using SDL_Scancode values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are macros.
You are offsetting a pointer to NULL by a macro value, and then trying to dereference it.
That's the cause of the segmentation fault (SIGSEGV).

```
Uint8* keys = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL); // NOT "keys = NULL;"
if (keys[SDLK_LEFT]) rect2.x -= 2;
if (keys[SDLK_RIGHT]) rect2.x += 2;
if (keys[SDLK_DOWN]) rect2.y += 2;
if (keys[SDLK_UP]) rect2.y -= 2;
```

Keep in mind that this is an internal array. You are not supposed to free it! This is a common mistake... "I am getting a copy of the list from the library, so I better delete it later to avoid memory leaks." But actually this is not allocated by `SDL_GetKeyboardState`, rather the function just gives you a pointer to the internal storage of the key states. So check the rest of your program and if you were freeing this, stop it because that also will contribute to an application crash.

---

**EDIT**
Alright, so here's the TRUE problem!

You're offsetting the address `keys` by `SDLK_LEFT`. The `SDLK_...` macros are not intended to be used for this purpose! Instead, offset by `SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT`, `SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT`, `SDL_SCANCODE_UP`, and `SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN`.

Since the `SDLK_...` macros aren't intended for this purpose, they are different values. Probably the reason you are getting a segmentation fault is that these are defined to large values that extend far beyond the length of the array `keys`.

Comment: I modified the code but I have the same problem like before . Maybe it helps when I post the whole sourcecode(it's not very long). I am goint to edit it in my Question.

Comment: I edited it, the issue is that you should use `SDL_SCANCODE_...`s instead of `SDLK_...`s.